# How to display the QR Code to my other Website?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, qr-code

How can I show the details of a user coming from my generated QR Code which consist of this url http://localhost:9000/api/user/ :Memb_ID?

Whereas the url is a JSON.

```
 {
"ID": 102,
"Memb_ID": "5555",
"First_Name": "Fname",
"Middle_Name": "Mname",
"Last_Name": "Lname",
"Address": "Hahahw"
}
```

I made a qr code application that generates qr code for every data in my database. As I said above, the QR Code consist of a URL which points to the user details. Here is my code snippet on how I achieved this.

```
    <b-modal :id="'modal1-' + result.Memb_ID" centered title="QR">
    <div class="showQR text-center">
        <qrcode-vue
         value="'http://localhost:8080/#/show/user/' + result.Memb_ID"
         :size="size"
         level="H"
        ></qrcode-vue>
     </div>
   </b-modal>
```

and this is my code snippet on my backend that gets a single member data from my database.

```
    router.get('/user/:Memb_ID', function (req, res) {
    let sql = "SELECT * FROM Member WHERE Memb_ID = ?";
    myDB.query(sql, req.params.Memb_ID, function (err, rows) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Your query has error.");
        } else {
            console.log(rows);
            res.send(rows);
        }
    });
});
```

This is how I show every data in my database using that route http://localhost:9000/api/user/Memb_ID on my backend and I want that data to be displayed on this route http://localhost:8080/#/show/user/ coming from my generated QR Code.